# toJSON on Backbone.Collection#where?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm not sure why, but I can't get this to work.

```
var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

friends.where({job: "Musketeer"}).toJSON()
```

I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toJSON'`.

What I'm I doing wrong and how do I convert my filtered collection into JSON?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What the `Underscore.where` method returns is an `Array` not a `Backbone.Collection` so it has not the `toJSON` method defined.

So you can make two things:

### Iterate over elements and map the result:

```
var result = friends.where({job: "Musketeer"});
_.map( result, function( model ){ return model.toJSON(); } );
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/wbBX9)

### Implement a Collection searcher method that returns a proper Backbone.Collection:

```
var Friends = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    search: function( opts ){
        var result = this.where( opts );
        var resultCollection = new Friends( result );

        return resultCollection;
    }
});

var myFriends = new Friends([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

myFriends.search({ job: "Musketeer" }).toJSON();​
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/fguillen/ut89Q)

Answer (score 5):

`toJSON` is a confusing method name : http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-toJSON

> **toJSON** `collection.toJSON()`
>
> Return an array containing the attributes hash of each model in the collection. This can be used to serialize and >persist the collection as a whole. The name of this method is a bit confusing, because it conforms to JavaScript's >JSON API.

if you want to convert your collection to a JSON string, use `JSON.stringify`

```
var friends = new Backbone.Collection([
  {name: "Athos",      job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Porthos",    job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "Aramis",     job: "Musketeer"},
  {name: "d'Artagnan", job: "Guard"},
]);

JSON.stringify( friends.where({job: "Musketeer"}) );
```

Note that `where` returns an array, not a Backbone collection, you would have to build a new collection to use the `toJSON` method.