# Backbone.js | Filter Collection data

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

I am trying to filter some data from my collection. I am using where method for the job but it is returning an empty array. Here is the code.

*Model:*

```
return Backbone.Model.extend({
            urlRoot: server_url + "tasks",
            defaults: {
                'id': null,
                'title': '',
                'description': '',
                'deadline': null,
                'priority': 1,
                'status': 1,
                'key': '',
                'priority_name': '',
                'status_name': ''
            }
    });
```

*Collection:*

```
return Backbone.Collection.extend({
        url: server_url + "tasks",
        model: TaskModel
    });
```

And using it like:

```
var taskList = new TaskList();
taskList.fetch({
          data: $.param({key: $.cookie('SID')}),
          success: function(collection, response){
            if(response.error){
              window.location.replace('#logout');
            }
          }
        });
taskList.where({status: 1});
```

taskList have all the data in it. It is not empty.
I have tried many combinations but hard luck every time.

I have also consulted from following posts but same result.

[Backbone collection where clause with OR condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208044/backbone-collection-where-clause-with-or-condition)

[Filter backbone collection by attribute value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11762105/filter-backbone-collection-by-attribute-value)

[toJSON on Backbone.Collection#where?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10548685/tojson-on-backbone-collectionwhere)

What I am missing here?

Comment: If you're initializing the collection and then querying the data on the next line, how is the data getting into the collection? If you're `fetch`ing it in the constructor, then this is a concurrency issue - the `fetch` call has not yet returned by the time you query it.

Comment: Are you sure that when you call the `where` function the collection has already been fetched? Try this: `taskList.fetch({ success: function(){ taskList.where({status:1}); }});`

Comment: I have edited the post to show the fetch process

Comment: I have also checked the 'where' in success function but still the empty array :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the code you've posted, but then you're not showing us the population of your `Collection`. Remember that `Backbone.Collection.where` simply takes a `literal` and returns an array of matched `Backbone.Model`'s. I have taken your code and simplified it to demonstrate a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/CK3Hz/

**Edited as per comments below**

`Backbone.Collection.fetch`'s `success` callback receives `(collection, response, options)` arguments. If you are to perform the `where` on `collection`, this should work.

I have provided [another jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3qGKt/) to demonstrate using event propagation which I assume is your end goal.

Comment: The code you have posted seems to be the same in sense. Is there any other thing which I am doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, as already mentioned @Ingro above, you are calling `where` without knowing whether the `taskList` has data. Try moving `where` inside the `success` callback. If this is not feasible you could consider [triggering an event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-trigger) inside `success` to something else that performs the `where`

Comment: I have checked it moving it in success callback. But again empty array :(